# Display a letter from a particular string

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a excel sheet which contains certain string want to display the letter  according to my examples required output.

below is the code i tried to get my desired output? help to make changes to my code  any help is appreciated....

```
data test;
set work.rr;
full=scan(full,-5);
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `scan()` function, but with a negative 2nd parameter, i.e. working backwards from the end of the string, and remember to specify the delimiter, i.e. `\` :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  prefix = substr(scan(full,-2,'\'),1,1) ;
run ;
```

Comment: Why do you need a macro? If you only want the `prefix` column, simply add a `keep prefix ;` statement to the above example.